# How to fix "go get: warning: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=auto in GOPATH/src"

Tags: go

I'm trying to install golint with the command: `go get -u golang.org/x/lint/golint`.
And I think I got two problems:

```
go get: warning: 
    modules disabled by GO111MODULE=auto in GOPATH/src;
    ignoring ../go.mod;
    see 'go help modules'

package golang.org/x/lint/golint: 
unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/lint/golint" (https fetch: Get https://golang.org/x/lint/golint?go-get=1: dial tcp 216.58.200.192:443: i/o timeout)
```

I then try to install golang/tools, also failed...

```
package golang.org/x/tools: unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/tools" (https fetch: Get https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1: dial tcp 216.58.200.192:443: i/o timeout)
```

Comment: Or is this just a internet block? Should I manually git clone the golang/tool repository?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you have a `go.mod` file inside $GOPATH/ (under `$GOPATH/go.mod`). You should remove that. Also, since you are using Go 1.11 or newer, you can run the `go get` command from well outside of GOPATH/any directory containing a `go.mod` file either directly or in a parent directory, and then the command should work.

Answer (score 92):

I ran this command

```
export GO111MODULE="on"
```

and that worked for me...

Answer (score 28):

Also got this error when trying to work with `vgo`

Removing GOROOT (you don't need to explicitly set `GOROOT`, Modern versions of Go can figure it out on their own based on the location of the go binary that you run), updating my GOPATH and `export GO111MODULE="on"` resolved the issue.

GOPATH see in [here](https://golang.org/cmd/go/)

> GOPATH may be set to a colon-separated list of paths inside which Go code, package objects, and executables may be found.
>
> Set a GOPATH to use goinstall to build and install your own code and external libraries outside of the Go tree (and to avoid writing Makefiles).

Comment: For Windows run `set` instead of `export`

Comment: `set GO111MODULE=on` for Windows, without quotes

Answer (score 18):

type following on command line or powershell:

```
go env -w GO111MODULE=on
```

should solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

At window10, I run the command:

```
go env -w GO111MODULE=on
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `go env -w GO111MODULE=on`

and just run this: `go install github.com/beego/bee@latest`
and it works