# Why can AppEngine Not Find Mailgun Pakage

Tags: go, google-app-engine, mailgun

I have my Golang App Engine project. I'm no expert of Go and so the package manager is a bit of a mystery to me. I haven't had any issues until now. When I try to use the MailGun Api, it is saying it can't resolve the dependency. I import mailgun like this:
`import "github.com/mailgun/mailgun-go"`.

However when I try to run: `gcloud app deploy` I get the following error:

```
 GO111MODULE=auto, but no go.mod found, so building with dependencies from GOPATH
main-package: MyPackage
2020/05/28 08:44:25 Staging second-gen Standard app (GOPATH mode): failed analyzing C:\Users\myUserName\go\src\MyPackage: cannot f
ind package "github.com/mailgun/mailgun-go/v4/events" in any of:
        ($GOROOT not set)
        C:\Users\MyUserName\go\src\github.com\mailgun\mailgun-go\v4\events (from $GOPATH)
GOPATH: C:\Users\MyUserName\go
```

When I navigate to `C:\Users\MyUserName\go\src\github.com\mailgun\mailgun-go` exists but there is no folders `v4` and `events`... Not sure what the issue is and where it is getting the events folder. Thanks for an help!

Comment: `/v4` means it's a Go module, at version 4. You'll need to `go mod init` for it to work properly.

Comment: When I run `go mod init` I get `modules disabled inside GOPATH/src by GO111MODULE=auto; see 'go help modules'` I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56475510/9609442 but I cannot find a go.mod file anywhere. I don't understand I have imported packages and it has worked for this project, why now is it not working??

Comment: I had to run `set GO111MODULE=on`. Then when I ran `go mod init` it deployed! Not sure what was wrong but glad it is working know. @Flimzy if you make your comment an answer I will accept and upvote. Thanks alot!!

Comment: I spoke to soon, My build to App Engine failed with an exception. It apparently did not like me setting GO111MODULE=on and is throwing a very large stack trace error. Really confused on where to go from here.

Comment: A stack trace will be unrelated to go modules. Stack traces happen at runtime, modules are purely compile-time.

Comment: @Flimzy Sorry, it was a build log, not a stack trace. But I think the issue of it is I set GO111MODULE to on instead of auto

Comment: But If i have it to auto then I get the error above...

Comment: Well what does the build log _say_?  And which version of Go are you using?

Comment: 1.12. I'm not sure if I paste the whole build log it will do much, it fails at GO111MODULE=on I'm attempting @thwd 's solution and then I will run `go mod init` and go from there.

Comment: "It fails" is obviously not a helpful description. If you want help, you'll need to include your log.

Comment: I'm posting the log in the question as it is too long for the comments

Comment: Yes, it should obviously be in the question, not in comments.

Comment: Alright so it is resolved. The new weird long build log was because my go.mod was using the wrong version of mailgun. Now it appears to be working. The important parts were executing `set GO111MODULE=on` and running go mod init. @Flimzy if you want to post the answer you said or I can post an answer describing my steps. Thanks for sticking with me here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/vX` convention is used by Go modules to distinguish between different major versions. This means you need to be using Go modules to consume such a package.

To do this, you'll need to run `go mod init` within your project's root directory.

Further, if you're using an older version of Go (1.11 or 1.12), you'll need to set `GO111MODULE=on` to ensure that your code is treated as a Go module.